# gwt textbox add change handler

Tags: java, gwt, textbox

i have a textbox received from designer.but i wrote action in GWT.
the problem is textbox is empty but when textbox is filled by value by pressing button then alert box will be displayed informed that value has been changed.
but not worked.help me.

```
  TextBox zip1 = null;

  function onModuleLoad() {
    zip1 = TextBox.wrap(DOM.getElementById("zip1"));
    zip1.addChangeHandler(zip1ChangeAction());
 }

private ChangeHandler zip1ChangeAction() {
   return new ChangeHandler() {
      public void onChange(ChangeEvent event) {
         Window.alert("change fired");
      }
   };
}
```

Comment: I wrote the above code.i have a textbox but it has empty but when it fills with text then I want to show an alert but not executed.
is there any opinion

Comment: It may help people to understand your question if you fixed the formatting.

Comment: **function** onModuleLoad? :D Are you sure you have a textbox by the id `zip1` in your HTML file?

Answer (score 14):

It seems that what you want is [`ValueChangeHandler`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/event/logical/shared/ValueChangeHandler.html):

```
textBox.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<String> event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```